# Mac: Sqlite3, OperationalError, unable to open database file, interacting with file over the local network

Tags: macos, sqlite, networking

(Mac related)

```
sqlite3.connect('/Volumes/admin/Library/Messages/chat.db')
```

In my Python script I'm trying to have it interact with the messages chat logs from another machine on the same network. I know the path is pointing to the right place, and I know the script works on my machine and the remote machine when run locally, but when I try to run it from my machine using the logs from the other machine I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I used to get this error when I ran this script on my computer running Mojave locally, and to resolve it I had to give Terminal full disk access.

The remote Mac is running High Sierra so it has the access by default (confirmed by the fact I can run it locally on the remote Mac without issue)

Does anyone know how I can resolve this permissions problem with running a script that interacts with the logs from another Mac's library over the network?

Thanks for any help!